# Columbia Omni Tech is not "re-appliable"

Tags: gear, waterproofing

Since Omni-tech is not DWR (durable water repellent), there is nothing to re-apply? Just follow care instructions to keep it grime free, correct? e.g. It can not be made "more" waterproof?

Comment: This likely makes sense to those familiar with the item. But can you add a little more information so the rest of us can understand it as well?

Answer (score 2):

Omni Tech is just Columbia's internally branded multi-layer waterproof/breathable membrane. Like any membrane (GoreTex, eVent, Deminax, etc) it'll typically be paired with a DWR for improved performance. I'd be shocked if any Omni Tech layer doesn't have a factory coating of DWR. So aside from keeping your clothes grime free, you can certainly re-apply DWR. DWR technically doesn't make it "more waterproof", but it makes your jacket seem more waterproof by preventing wetting-out and improving breathability.

In short, if you've notice a decline in your Omni Tech's performance it might be worth trying to reapply a spray on DWR like Nikwax.